# comparison of multiple input fields with same class name but not same id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to make jquery/javascript function which compare multiple values with each other if one of them comes out different then echo "Values are different" next to every field present in html body.

```
<input name="flag2" type="text" id="flag2" class="flags">

<input name="flag3" type="text" id="flag3" class="flags">

<input name="flag4" type="text" id="flag4" class="flags">

<input name="flag5" type="text" id="flag5" class="flags">

<input name="flag6" type="text" id="flag6" class="flags">
```

Note: I use a button with jquery function to add new field on press, is using appendTo to add more fields. sometimes i have more or less fields, the jquery function must be dynamic, to apply on the number of input fields set.

Comment: SO isn't a place to come and ask for people to write your code for you.

Comment: and what do u mean different.

Comment: I expect you know how to select and loop through elements using jQuery? Your question is mixed with both jQuery, UI and business-logic, making it very hard to answer/help you.

Comment: the scenario is <script> will check every flag value (i.e. flag1, flag2 ..) and compare values with each other. if all are same then display Values are same and if one them comes out different then loop will break and display Values are different. I just want the comparison logic with each other of every field. lets say if fields are 100 then all must be compared with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try each() function

```
$(".flags").each(function(){
 alert(this.value);
});
```

[Link for references](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the job with a help of two each functions in `Jquery` below,

Get the selector common for all the input tags say `.flags`, then create a loop to get all the `DOM` objects

```
var temp; var start=0; var boolN=true;
$( "input.flags" ).each(function( index ) {

    if (start==0) {
        temp = $( this ).text();
    } else if (temp = $( this ).text()) {
        temp = $( this ).text();
    } else {
        boolN = false;
    }
});
```

Now loop the span or your custom tag to show the message. I have used a span tag here,

```
$( "span" ).each(function( index ) {
    if (boolN) {
        $( this ).html("Values are Simillar");
    } else {
        $( this ).html("Values are Different");
    }
});
```

Now couple both the above methods in a custom method and bind a `click` event of a button like

```
$("button").click(function () {

  var temp; var start=0; var boolN=true;
    $( "input.flags" ).each(function( index ) {

        if (start==0) {
            temp = $( this ).text();
        } else if (temp = $( this ).text()) {
            temp = $( this ).text();
        } else {
            boolN = false;
        }
    });
 $( "span" ).each(function( index ) {
        if (boolN) {
            $( this ).html("Values are Simillar");
        } else {
            $( this ).html("Values are Different");
        }
    });

});
```

[Working Example at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BalaVaradarajan/LRAu6/3/)